# Excel VBA Change Row Height based on Find Value

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. The first has 2 columns of data. The second is a formatted schedule. I want to find the values in the first column of data in the schedule then:

Substitute the data in the second column
Increase the Row Height of the cell with the new value by 5.
Change the Font of all the cells in the Schedule to Calibri.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```
Public Sub FindReplace()
    Dim AllCells As Range
    Dim myList As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myHeight As Double

    Set AllCells = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells
    AllCells.Font.Name = "Calibri"

    Set myList = Sheets("FindReplace").Range("A1:C200")
    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells

    For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
        myRange.Select
        Selection.Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
        ActiveCell.RowHeight = myHeight
        myHeight = myHeight + 5
        Selection.RowHeight = myHeight

        myRange.Replace cel.Value, cel.Offset(0, 2), LookAt:=xlWhole     
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: Write `Option Explicit` on top of the module. Then go to `Debug->Compile` and edit your code until it is compiling. Then read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201705180959419010448

Comment: Side note: Instead of `Sheets` you should always work with `Worksheets`, because the sheets collection also contains charts etc. where eg. `Sheets("A Cart").Range` will fail.

Comment: "Not working" - an oft seen and never helpful phrase. Please be more specific - do you receive an error message, does the code run but not do what you want, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindReplace()

    Dim AllCells        As Range
    Dim myList          As Range
    Dim myRange         As Range
    Dim myHeight        As Double
    Dim cel             'not declared in your code, but its a good idea to do it

    Set AllCells = Sheets("T3").Cells
    AllCells.Font.Name = "Calibri"

    Set myList = Sheets("T2").Range("A1:C200")
    Set myRange = Sheets("T3").Cells

    For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
        myRange.Parent.Activate
        myRange.Select
        'Selection.Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate

        myHeight = myHeight + 5

        If myHeight < 410 Then
            'Selection.RowHeight = myHeight
            ActiveCell.RowHeight = myHeight
        End If
        myRange.Replace cel.Value, cel.Offset(0, 2), LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next cel
End Sub
```

What has been changed?

- The name of the sheets.
- the active sheet of the `cel` element is activated with `myRange.Parent.Activate`
- A condition for 410 Height is introduced.
- Option explicit on top

In general, the code is not of a high quality, because it uses `Select` and `Activate` and this is against best practices for performance and debugging reasons.

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt reply. But I get and error. "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. When I select "debug" it points to the line "Selection.Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate". What would you suggest

Comment: Just remove the line and try again

Comment: The macro runs without that line, but it changes every row's height in the second spreadsheet to 405! You said I was using bad practice. Can you write a better script for this from scratch? I'm a bit new to VBA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindReplace()

Dim myList, myRange, CelA, celB As Range

Set myRange = Sheets("T3").Cells
myRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
Set myList = Sheets("T2").Range("A1:c200")
For Each CelA In myList.Columns(1).Cells
    If CelA <> "" Then
        Set celB = myRange.Cells.Find(What:=CelA.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not celB Is Nothing Then
            If celB.RowHeight < 410 Then celB.RowHeight = celB.RowHeight + 5
            myRange.Replace CelA.Value, CelA.Offset(0, 2), LookAt:=xlWhole
        End If
    End If
Next CelA
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I'm getting that same Run-time error '91' "Object variable or With block variable not set on the line "If celB.RowHeight < 410 ". It seems to be indicating that celB is not properly declared. I deleted that IF statement and the same error appeared on the rest of that line. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: Latest, Office365

Comment: Thankyou Massimo Griffani. That works now. Can you give any insight into what the key to success was?

Comment: The run-time error was due to the fact that CelB was Nothing, because no cell had been found with the desired value. So only if the cell exists the operation must be done. In addition, in my test, I have set not to look for empty values ​​(CellA <>> "")